# Linting passes when executed from a gulp task, but it should fail

Tags: javascript, gulp, eslint

I am doing linting on my JavaScript code with this command:

```
eslint src/**/*.js
```

This finds hundreds of linting errors.

I am trying to make linting part of a pipeline. Therefore, I made a gulp task for it.

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const eslint = require('gulp-eslint');

gulp.task('lint', () => {
    gulp.src(['src/**/*.js'])
        .pipe(eslint())
        .pipe(eslint.format())
        .pipe(eslint.failAfterError());
});
```

However, when I run `gulp lint`, it passes:

```
Starting 'lint'...
Finished 'lint' after 35 ms
```

I don't understand why it passes. I also tried this:

```
gulp.task('lint', () => {
    gulp.src(['src/**/*.js'])
        .pipe(eslint())
});
```

But this also passes.

Any idea why `gulp lint` doesn't fail with a linting error?

Comment: `gulp.src` returns a promise. Try returning that from your task function so Gulp will handle it properly

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. So how should I modify my code?

Comment: I have expanded this comment into a proper answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need Gulp to call the task and wait for it to complete then you need to return a [JavaScript Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) from the *task* function.

In this case, adding the keyword `return` before your `gulp.src` call in your *lint* funciton means that the Promise that the `gulp.src` returns is passed up to the underlying mechanism that Gulp uses and as such, Gulp can get the result from your linting process.

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const eslint = require('gulp-eslint');

gulp.task('lint', () => {
    return gulp.src(['src/**/*.js'])
        .pipe(eslint())
        .pipe(eslint.format())
        .pipe(eslint.failAfterError());
});
```

Comment: Without the `return` statement, what was the function returning?

Comment: The gulp-task function call will have returned 'undefined' so Gulp has no way of seeing when your pipeline has finished. I still see eslint output on my console but that might be down to how eslint is configured or the shell I am using.